# Java. Фибоначчи

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. Имеется работоспособный код, который выводит числа Фибоначчи:

```
public class Fibonachi2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[10];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(i > 2) {
        a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Результат: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Но меня интересует как он выводит первые две единицы? Ведь по условию:

```
 if(i > 2) {
    a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
```

он должен выводить элементы на экран, начиная с 4 элемента массива (System.out.print(a[3] + " "); и т.д.).

Comment: Почему не включить отладчик и отладить цикл поэтапно, посмотрев что там происходит внутри?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На экран и выводятся элементы, начиная с четвертого.

При `i=3` получим:

```
a[3] = a[1] + a[2] = 1 + 0 = 1
```

При `i=4`:

```
a[4] = a[2] + a[3] = 0 + 1 = 1
```

При создании массива, он инициализируется нулями, потом Вы явно инициализируете первый и второй элементы единицами, остальные элементы при этом остаются нулями.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы инициализируете массив `int[] a = new int[10];`, то он заполняется нулями:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Далее после строк

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 1;
```

Получаем

```
{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Ну а далее все просто: при срабатывании первый раз условия `if(i > 2)`, т .е. когда `i = 3` получаем:

```
 a[i - 2] + a[i - 1]; => a[1] + a[2] => 1 + 0 => 1
```

при `i = 4`

```
 a[i - 2] + a[i - 1]; => a[2] + a[3] => 1 + 0 => 1
```

и вот вам  две единицы

А далее по возрастающей...